# JSON data parsing from html source in python

Tags: python, json

I have a bunch of data that looks like this:

> {"Game":"Chess","title":"just for
>   fun!","size":"2","entriesData":["PLAYERNAME","IMAGEHERE"],"entryFee":1,"prizeSummary","gameId":"9436","tableSpecId":"1079","dateUpdated":1389810809648,"dateCreated":1389659697294,"stack":235,"entryHTML":null}

with basically a bunch of entries one after another.

I want to parse this data to get playername, game type, etc.

I know I should use the JSON library to accomplish this.

The page I get the code from has a bunch of HTML on it as well. Is it okay to use the json.load on the html, or should I strip that from it first?

I'm not really entirely sure where to begin solving this problem, and am a bit confused by the JSON documentation.

Any tips or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here -- retrieve a page with Python and then find part of that page and parse it as JSON?

Comment: Yes. I have retrieved the page, and I basically have the HTML, along with the huge chunk of JSON in it. I want to get the data and store it in a table basically.

Comment: If you try to parse the entire page a JSON document, it will fail. You'll need to get just the JSON data out of the HTML response and then give that to the JSON parser.

Comment: Maybe first parse the HTML (using BeautifulSoup, for instance) in order to extract the JSON from the HTML. Then, use `json.loads` to parse the JSON.

Comment: is the client posting to your python code or is the python code fetching it from a url?

Answer (score 0):

```
jsonDictionaryRepresentation = json.loads(yourJsonObject)
```

then operate on it as a dictionary.  Implicit in `json.loads` is that it is in fact valid json so yes, if the payload you are getting has a response body that includes something other than json, you'd have to strip that out.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`json.loads()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) function to parse a JSON string into a dictionary or array object.  For example:

```
>>> import json
>>> x = json.loads('{"Game":"Chess","title":"just for fun!","size":"2","entriesData":["PLAYERNAME","IMAGEHERE"],"entryFee":1,"prizeSummary":"","gameId":"9436","tableSpecId":"1079","dateUpdated":1389810809648,"dateCreated":1389659697294,"stack":235,"entryHTML":null}')
>>> print x
{u'entryHTML': None, u'entriesData': [u'PLAYERNAME', u'IMAGEHERE'], u'prizeSummary': u'', u'title': u'just for fun!', u'dateCreated': 1389659697294L, u'Game': u'Chess', u'gameId': u'9436', u'entryFee': 1, u'tableSpecId': u'1079', u'dateUpdated': 1389810809648L, u'stack': 235, u'size': u'2'}
>>> print x['Game']
Chess
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks! I managed to get my JSON string byu itself without the HTML, but im getting this error when i try to json.load it. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Wilson/PycharmProjects/DraftPwn/Selenium.py", line 49, in <module>
    x = json.loads(json_text)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 433 - line 1 column 904192 (char 432 - 904191)

Comment: @Wilson: Sounds like your JSON data is invalid at column 433.  Or perhaps you're including extra data in your string after the JSON ends -- make sure you're only parsing exactly the JSON data and nothing more.

Comment: If I have multiple game entries, does it load them all up into one dictionary or how would I handle that? I'm assuming I cant just do x['Game'] to get all of them?

Comment: @Wilson: No, in this case, keys would get overwritten.  `json.loads('{"x":"y","x":"z"}')` results in just the one key `{u'x': u'z'}`.  The [JSON spec](http://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc4627#section-2.2) says that "The names within an object SHOULD be unique.".  If your names aren't unique, I strongly recommend you change your data model (e.g. use an array as the value).